# Sending Email from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, email, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to send an email from a class which extends ***Broadcastreceiver***.

But i am getting the following error.

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
                                                                      at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1026)
                                                                      at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1013)
                                                                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:284)
                                                                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:284)
                                                                      at mimbarsoft.com.callspy.InternetConnecton.onReceive(InternetConnecton.java:37)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2550)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:162) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1440) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

After seeing some stackoverflow post i added ***setFlags*** but still i am getting the same error.

Here is my code

```
public class InternetConnecton extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
        Toast.makeText(context,"Internet is connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        emailIntent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"ahmedshihab14@yandex.com"});
        emailIntent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"CallSPY");
        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();
        while(!IncomingCall.savedFile.isEmpty()){
            File f = IncomingCall.savedFile.poll();
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            uris.add(uri);
        }
        emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uris);
        emailIntent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent.createChooser(emailIntent,"Sending mail"));

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(context,"no internet",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

Does anyone got any solution??

Comment: Do not pop up an activity in the middle of what the user is doing. Display a `Notification`, please.

Comment: @CommonsWare may you suggest anything that i don't have to pop up an acitivity in middle to send an email in background?

Comment: For sending email in the background, you have to have the consent of the user via GET_ACCOUNTS permission, as well as access to the Gmail API (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/). However, user needs to be logged in for this. Also, as @CommonsWare suggested, you might not want to interrupt what the user is doing by showing him a randomly spawning activity. Please consider using a notification for that purpose. 
More to read:
- https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending
- https://www.javatpoint.com/java-mail-api-tutorial

Comment: Your code does not send an email in the background. It will display an activity to the user. You would need to use some third-party library (e.g., JavaMail) to send email without a user interface.